# Bash script doesn't end after child process output

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, io-redirection

I have a `launcher.sh` script which is supposed to do some work before launching another executable, and then exit. The other executable is supposed to stay alive after the launcher exits.

Sometimes, the `launcher.sh` doesn't end, even though its execution reached the `exit 0` point. I reproduced this behavior with the following script :

```sh
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                            

function service() {
    echo stdout $0
    echo stderr $0 >&2

    while true; do
        sleep 3600
    done
}

exec > >(awk '{ print strftime("[%FT%T]"), $0; fflush(); }') 2>&1

echo "$0 started"

service&

echo "$0 ended"

exit 0
```

Which outputs the following :

```
[2020-10-07T16:39:18] ./launcher.sh started                                                                            
[2020-10-07T16:39:18] ./launcher.sh ended
[2020-10-07T16:39:18] stdout ./launcher.sh
[2020-10-07T16:39:18] stderr ./launcher.sh
```

So I expect the main `launcher.sh` process to be gone, and the other one to be `sleep`ing. But in reality, the main one is still here, waiting for some more output to pipe into `awk`.

```
17359 pts/0    S      0:00 /bin/bash ./launcher.sh
17361 pts/0    S      0:00  \_ sleep 3600
17358 pts/0    S      0:00 /bin/bash ./launcher.sh
17360 pts/0    S      0:00  \_ awk { print strftime("[%FT%T]"), $0; fflush(); }
```

I noticed this behavior occurs only because `service` outputs some text. When nothing is output by `service`, then the main `launcher.sh` process does exit, and the child one does stay alive.

Is there a way to make the main `launcher.sh` process exit (while still keeping the eventual early output of `service` logged) ?

Comment: BTW, re: `function service() {`, it should just be `service() {` with no `function`; see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 0):

When you run `exec > >(awk '{ print strftime("[%FT%T]"), $0; fflush(); }') 2>&1`, that changes stdout and stderr to point to the subshell started for your process substitution -- not just for your script, but for *processes your script starts*. That includes `service`.

Add an extra `exec` to your redirection command to eliminate the retention of the subshell that started awk (`awk` itself is reading stdin directly; the parent shell serves no useful purpose):

```
exec > >(exec awk '{ print strftime("[%FT%T]"), $0; fflush(); }') 2>&1
```

...and if you want `service` to no longer be writing to your process substitution that runs awk, the easiest thing is to just redirect stdout and stderr (and stdin for good measure, if the intent is really to run it as a service) when you start it:

```
service </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```